# ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer

Tags: python

i am new and i need help; the below code for  "Face mask Detection "

```
for row in transfer_learning_model.layers:

  row.trainable = False

optimizer = Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=learning_rate / epoch)

cnn.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer,

metrics=["accuracy"])

history = cnn.fit(

generator.flow(training_data, training_label, batch_size=batch_size),

steps_per_epoch=len(training_data) // batch_size,

validation_data=(testing_data, testing_label),

validation_steps=len(testing_data) // batch_size,

epochs=epoch)

cnn.evaluate(testing_data, testing_label)

plot_acc_loss(history, 25)
```

when i run it ,it give this Error:

```
ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, pleasecheck the docstring for valid arguments, or use the legacy optimizer, e.g., tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam.
```

i tryed many ways but I failed..